# How to Translate REGEXMATCH formula from Google Sheets to R

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I've got columns in Google Sheets with headers like the following:

Complete_Fall11 Complete_Spr12  Complete_Fall12 Complete_Spr13  Complete_Fall13 Complete_Spr14

And below each of them I've got a Cell with the following formula:

```
=IF($O2>=IF(REGEXMATCH(AN$1,".*Fall.*"),VALUE("20"&REGEXEXTRACT(AN$1,".*(\d\d)$")&"1100"),IF(REGEXMATCH(AN$1,".*Spr.*"),VALUE("20"&REGEXEXTRACT(AN$1,".*(\d\d)$")&"0400"),IF(REGEXMATCH(AN$1,".*Sum.*"),VALUE("20"&REGEXEXTRACT(AN$1,".*(\d\d)$")&"0500"),))),"1","NA")
```

This code basically...

- looks to see if the value in column "Enrollment.End"
  is greater than or equal to..

  - 20__0500 for Summer, 
    20__1100 for Fall,
    and 20__0400 for Spring,
- ... and extracts the year to put in:

  - For instance, the column with header 'Complete_Fall11' would look for
    a value that is greater than or equal to 20111100 in the column
    'Enrollment.

In R my dataframe name is NSCH, and I have the same column headers. So there are two parts to this question:

1. How do I recode values in column NSCH$Enrollment.End to 'Complete_Fall11' where if the value in NSCH$Enrollment.End > 20111100 is greater than or equal to 20111100 it returns "1" and if it's less than it returns 'NA'.
2. Is it feasible to write code to automatically extract the month from whether the variable name (aka column header) contains "Fall", "Spring", or "Summer", or is it better for me to just write a script making all that explicit?*

Example Dataframe:

```
Enrollment.End:
20041221
20050509
20051222
```

Desired Output:

```
Complete_Fall06  Complete_Fall05
0                0
0                0
0                1
```

*The beauty of R is I can write a script. The whole reason I have this complicated regular expression in Google Sheets is that it takes the place of a script in terms of automating functions for me.

Comment: I suggest adding a minimal example input data frame and the desired output data frame to your posting in order to maybe make things more obvious and easier to "consume".

Comment: Is `20110500` a date? And if so, why is `20050509` not greater then `20050500`? Maybe you can use sth like `df <- data.frame(e=as.Date(c("20041221","20050509","20051222"), format="%Y%m%d"));n <- c("Complete_Fall06", "Complete_Fall05");transform(expand.grid(e=df$e, n=n, stringsAsFactors=F), res=e>=as.Date(paste0("20", substr(n, nchar(n)-1, nchar(n)), "-05-01")) & format(e, "%y")==substr(n, nchar(n)-1, nchar(n)))`. It's a long shape, which you can reshape to the desired output.

Comment: Yes, 20110500 is a date, and 20050509 should be greater than 20050500. I'll change my question to indicate the correct output.